# How can i authenticate all the rest endpoint whithout specifying @authenticated annotation

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, quarkus

I have auhenticated some of rest endpont using the OIDC @Authenticated annotation .

But some the rest are present in resources folder (Its is drools file) which not authenticated bydefault.

Is there any way to authenticate all rest endpoint which is coming form that location (Like .security constraints)

Here is my application.yaml file

```
`
quarkus:

  oidc:
    auth-server-url: '${AUTH_SERVER_URL}'
    client-id: '${CLIENT_ID}'
    application-type: service`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`authenticated` HTTP security policy can help, for example:

```
quarkus.http.auth.permission.policy1.paths=/public/*,/services/*
quarkus.http.auth.permission.policy1.policy=authenticated
```

will do, see https://quarkus.io/guides/security-authorize-web-endpoints-reference